# Mongodb: $regexMatch after converting array $toString not working as expected

Tags: arrays, mongodb, design-patterns, lookup, tostring

I'm using Mongo's $regexMatch operator to find documents where at least part of a field matches the pattern, and this works fine for root-level fields, but the search document has an array with an array field inside. But how do I use it with array fields? I want to return a match if at least one of the array elements matches the pattern.

**an instance of each collection**

[Companies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvlxb.png)

[Flyers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsX1X.png)

```
db.companies.aggregate(
[{$geoNear: {
 near: {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [
   -3.128145200960907,
   -59.99944718666838
  ]
 },
 maxDistance: 10000,
 distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
 spherical: true
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'flyers',
 localField: '_id',
 foreignField: 'company',
 as: 'flyers'
}}, {$project: {
 _id: 1,
 socialReason: 1,
 'profile.logo': 1,
 flyers: {
  $filter: {
   input: '$flyers',
   as: 'flyers_ativados',
   cond: {
    $eq: [
     '$$flyers_ativados.status',
     'Ativado'
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}}, {$project: {
 flyers: {
  $filter: {
   input: '$flyers',
   as: 'flyers_ativados',
   cond: {
    $or: [
     {
      $regexMatch: {
       input: '$$flyers_ativados.title',
       regex: 'kuka'
      }
     },
     {
      $regexMatch: {
       input: '$$flyers_ativados.description',
       regex: 'kuka'
      }
     },
     {
      $regexMatch: {
       input: {
        $toString: '$$flyers_ativados.tags'
       },
       regex: 'carne'
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}}])
```

**MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Unsupported conversion from array to string in $convert with no onError value**

very grateful for any suggestion

Comment: Since you got error at `$project` stage, you can try to minimize your question by remove 
 `$geoNear` stage in your question. And show us some valid data after `$geoNear` stage and give a valid JSON as expected result. Edit your question.

Comment: The $geoNear stage is fundamental for joining the collection companies with flyers, notice that the collections flleyrs is joined and precisely at that moment the error happens when I apply toString

Comment: when I apply $reduce to the colelction flyers, the tags field, which is an array, is transformed into strings and that's what I need after running the lookkup, see: db.flyers.aggregate([ { $set: { tags: { $reduce: { input: "$tags", initialValue: "", in: { $concat: ["$$value", " ", "$$this"] } } } } },{"$match": {"$or": [{"title": {$regex :/kuca.*/i}},{"tags": {$regex :/eite/i}}] }} ])

Comment: Please don't use images for code/data/errors/etc. Also, if you have new info that would help clarify/elaborate your question, just edit your question and include it there.